# How to customize Windows "Performance Monitor"?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, performance, performance-monitoring, performance-counters

I'm wondering if that's possible to set a customized action counter that is not listed as one of the counters? e.g. a batch script that measure a time for running my application, and then notify the real-time graph the time it took to load it. Also I'd like to set its frequency.

If possible, please let me know how to apply.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can create perfmon counters [using .NET code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1skfb8y0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and thus [using PowerShell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh508994.aspx) too. A moderate amount of coding is required.